# Counting how many MySQL fields in a row are filled (or empty) from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to put together a method that would allow me to quantify how many fields in a row have been filled by a user.
and return a value that would reflect the degree of completion of the user's record. Such

```
as:
    User 1 = 100% complete
    User 2 = 80% complete
    User 3 = 60% complete
```

it's the same question here [Counting how many MySQL fields in a row are filled (or empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720725/counting-how-many-mysql-fields-in-a-row-are-filled-or-empty)

but what if I need to query from 4 tables with id?

I did this as try

```
<?php
   $userId = $pro->id;
   $completeProfile = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hired_person_info WHERE id=?");
   $completeProfile = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hired_education_info WHERE id=?");
   $completeProfile = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hired_job_info WHERE id=?");
   $completeProfile = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hired_ts_info WHERE id=?");
   $completeProfile->bind_param('i', $userId);

if ($completeProfile->execute()) {   
$result = $completeProfile->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
       $empty_count = 0;
       $count = count($row);
         for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
           if ($row[$i] === '' || $row[$i] === 'NULL')
           $empty_count++;

          $com = ((int)(100 * (1 - $empty_count / ($count - 1))));
           if ($com > 50) {
              echo "<span class='f_left width_autor textLeft GreenFont padding_8R'>".((int)(100 * (1 - $empty_count / ($count - 1))))."%</span>";
        } else {
             echo "".((int)(100 * (1 - $empty_count / ($count - 1))))."%";
     }
    }
  }
?>
```

but when I try to run the code it always give 8% complete even if I try to complete some of the profiles to make it 60% it doesn't it just give 8% or 100% if I complete the profile

now how can I write query the right way to make it work as expected.
Thanks.

Comment: I am not pro in PDO, but as i see, you are overwriting the `$completeProfile` variable, so you will get only the last querys results when `$completeProfile->execute()` happens.

Comment: so you think I should change the name of every query and execute every one again as `$completeProfile1->execute()` and `$completeProfile2->execute()` did I understand you right

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in my comment, i think, because you are overwriting your `$completeProfile` and not execute them, only the last one. Try something like this (not tested, because i do not have your table structure, and your custom db handler functions).

```
$userId = $pro->id;

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM hired_person_info WHERE id=?";
showUserPercentage($userId, $query1, $db);

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM hired_education_info WHERE id=?";
showUserPercentage($userId, $query2, $db);

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM hired_job_info WHERE id=?";
showUserPercentage($userId, $query3, $db);

$query4 = "SELECT * FROM hired_ts_info WHERE id=?";
showUserPercentage($userId, $query4, $db);

function showUserPercentage($userId, $query, $db) {
    $completeProfile = $db->prepare();
    $completeProfile->bind_param('i', $userId);
    if ($completeProfile->execute()) {
        $result = $completeProfile->get_result();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            $empty_count = 0;
            $count = count($row);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                if ($row[$i] === '' || $row[$i] === 'NULL') {
                    $empty_count++;
                }
            }
            $com = ((int) (100 * (1 - $empty_count / ($count - 1))));
            if ($com > 50) {
                echo "<span class='f_left width_autor textLeft GreenFont padding_8R'>" . ((int) (100 * (1 - $empty_count / ($count - 1)))) . "%</span>";
            } else {
                echo "" . ((int) (100 * (1 - $empty_count / ($count - 1)))) . "%";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mikky try this

```
<?php
   $personProfile = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hired_person_info AS t1
                                JOIN hired_education_info AS t2
                                ON t1.id=t2.uid
                                WHERE t1.id=? GROUP BY t1.id ");

if ($completeProfile->execute()) {   
$result = $completeProfile->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
       $empty_count = 0;
       $count = count($row);
         for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
           if ($row[$i] === '' || $row[$i] === 'NULL')
           $empty_count++;

          $com = ((int)(100 * (1 - $empty_count / ($count - 1))));
           if ($com > 50) {
              echo "<span class='f_left width_autor textLeft GreenFont padding_8R'>".((int)(100 * (1 - $empty_count / ($count - 1))))."%</span>";
        } else {
             echo "".((int)(100 * (1 - $empty_count / ($count - 1))))."%";
     }
    }
  }
?>
```