# Counting how many fields (in a row) are filled in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count how many columns in a row are not `NULL`.
The table is quite big (more than 100 columns), therefore I would like to **not** do it manually or using php (since I dont use php) using this approach [Counting how many MySQL fields in a row are filled (or empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720725/counting-how-many-mysql-fields-in-a-row-are-filled-or-empty).

Is there a simple query I can use in a select like `SELECT COUNT(NOT ISNULL(*)) FROM big_table;`

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The query cannot be that simple as the answer might be different on each row

Comment: So are you prepared to write a query that tests each column for each row in the table for a table with 100+ columns

Comment: If you have 100+ columns, and need to count the non-null columns, something is odd.

Comment: You can select your table's column names and generate your query from its result: `SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'xxx' AND table_name = 'yyy'`.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with comments above:

1. There is something wrong in the data since there is a need for such analysis.
2. You can't completely make it automatic.

But I have a recipe for you for simplifying the process. There are only 2 steps needed to achieve your aim.

Step 0. In the step1 you'll need to get the name of your table schema. Normally, the devs know in what schema does the table reside, but still... Here is how you can find it

```
select *
  from information_schema.tables
 where table_name = 'test_table';
```

Step 1. First of all you need to get the list of columns. Getting just the list of cols won't help you out at all, but this list is all we need to be able to create SELECT statement, right? So, let's make database to prepare select statement for us

```
select concat('select (length(concat(', 
              group_concat(concat('ifnull(', column_name, ', ''@@@'')') separator ','),
              ')) - length(replace(concat(', 
              group_concat(concat('ifnull(', column_name, ', ''@@@'')') separator ','),
              '), ''@@@'', ''''))) / length(''@@@'')
              from test_table')
  from information_schema.columns
 where table_schema = 'test'
   and table_name = 'test_table'
 order by table_name,ordinal_position;
```

Step 3. Execute statement you've got on step 2.

```
select (length(concat(.. list of cols ..)) - 
        length(replace(concat(.. list of cols .. ), '@@@', ''))) / length('@@@') 
  from test_table
```

The select looks tricky but it's simple: first replace all nulls with some symbols that you're sure you'll never get in those columns. I usually do that replacing nulls with "@@@". that what all that "ifnull"s are here for.

Next, count symbols with "length". In my case it was 14

After that, replace all "@@@" with blanks and count length again. It's 11 now. For that I was using "length(replace" functions together

Last, just divide (14 - 11) by a length of a replacement string ("@@@" - 3). You'll get 1. This is exactly amount of nulls in my test string.

Here's a [test case](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bKpCuD9EDDstCbTit3kscQ/0) you can play with

Do not hesitate to ask if needed